# Example Code imports are missing in jzy3d

Tags: java, maven, jzy3d

The Example code imports are missing. Does anyone know what I not including?

I got the imports for mvn from http://www.jzy3d.org/download-0.9.1.php

The example code is from https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/tree/master/jzy3d-javafx/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/javafx

and these three imports are causing problems. I didn't see any other mvn imports

```
import org.jzy3d.javafx.JavaFXChartFactory;
import org.jzy3d.javafx.JavaFXRenderer3d;
import org.jzy3d.javafx.controllers.mouse.JavaFXCameraMouseController;

        <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>jzy3d-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>jzy3d-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>jzy3d-api</artifactId>
           <version>0.9.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
       </dependency>-->

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jzy3d-snapshots</id>
        <name>Jzy3d Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>jzy3d-releases</id>
        <name>Jzy3d Releases</name>
        <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those classes are available in this maven dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jzy3d</groupId>
        <artifactId>jzy3d-javafx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add only the release repository.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jzy3d-releases</id>
        <name>Jzy3d Releases</name>
        <url>http://maven.jzy3d.org/releases </url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: As you can see from the commented out code I have tried that. With that one I get the same

Comment: I updated the maven pom to include only the release repo. I tested this and the imports just work fine. Did you try this?

Comment: Btw, you did not include this dependency in the question posted: jzy3d-javafx

Comment: sure, no problem!